# HTML5 Boilerplate and NetBeans

Tags: html, netbeans, boilerplate

Are there any instructions available about how to use HTML5 Boilerplate with NetBeans?

Comment: Do you want to know how to create an HTML5 template?

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 boilerplate is just a default template for HTML5 websites. If I get you right, you want to use it with Netbeans. The answer seems quite simple to me: Download, unzip and open up the files with your favourite editor (in your case, Netbeans w/ HTML). The boilerplate is mostly simple plain text; nothing fancy. They even tell you on their webpage:

> Boilerplate is not a framework, nor does it prescribe any philosophy of development, it's just got some tricks to get your project off the ground quickly and right-footed.

So just: Download, Unzip, Open, Enjoy.

Comment: Oh dang, didn't look at the date. Sry.